# MYSQL LIMIT. Is it possible to skip certain rows?

Tags: mysql, limit

Sorry if this question is confusing.

I have inherited a site that is already built, so I can't really do anything too drastic.

The MYSQL query on a certain page uses LIMIT to only show the relevant entries like this:

```
comtitlesub.idcts = %s LIMIT 1,3
```

Skipping the first record and displaying the following three records.
I have been asked to add a new record, which is fine, but this is record number 7. Records 5 and 6 are not supposed to display on this page so changing the query to:

```
comtitlesub.idcts = %s LIMIT 1,6
```

displays all 6 records as you would expect.

One confusing thing is that I have altered the ID's for each of the records so that my new one is ID 4, and yet this did not make a difference.

Is there a simple way to 'skip' the unwanted records or am I approaching this from the wrong direction?

Comment: Can you not further limit your results in a `WHERE` clause?:  `WHERE comtitlesub.idcts = %s AND someothercol NOT IN (3,4,6,1)`

Comment: Of course, you would want to use a column in `WHERE` that has stable data and doesn't rely on a numeric id that may change.

Comment: @michael Thanks for this, I will give this a go and report back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add "`order by comtitlesub.idcts`" at the end of you query, but before the limit clause.

```
... comtitlesub.idcts = %s ORDER BY comtitlesub.idcts LIMIT 1,6
```

basically, changing the id doesn't reorder them, rows are stored in order they have been created, and retrieved that way by default.

Comment: This is giving me the same results. But I hadn't considered using Order By for some reason so I'm going to experiment. Oh and thanks for explaining why changing the IDs didn't work :)

Comment: This fixed it for me when I used ORDER BY areas.id (The query utilised two tables). I got so hung up on trying to stretch LIMIT to do something it isn't intended to do that I didn't even consider doing it this way. Thanks

Comment: as @Michael said, doing somehting like `where id in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` or `where id betweeen (2 and 6)` (now that IDs have been redone) would really make us all sleep better ;)

Answer (score 1):

Andrew, `LIMIT` will delimit according to a specific order, in your case, coincidentally the default order was the same than ID order, now that you've changed it, you will need to order by ID:

```
ORDER BY comtitlesub.idcts
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can't believe I didn't even think to use Order By!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest course would be to modify your `WHERE` clause to exclude the rows you want excluded. For example:

```
WHERE comtitlesub.idcts = %s AND someothercol NOT IN ('cat','frog','kazoo')
```

Ideally for maintainability, you would want `someothercol` to hold stable data rather than a numeric ID which might change as your application data changes.

Comment: Many thanks for your time. The ORDER BY example gave me the 'quick fix' I needed.